Missing labels on Zebra printer
the zpl file sent from CUPS server to the printer has an extra ^xa in the code. Lebel starts with ^XA and ends with ^XZ, but on few print jobs where printer just blinks and does not print anything, we found that it has an ^xa just before ^XZ.
We are unable to find what is causing this. Any suggestion?
print jobs printing labels should not skip
